# Why there is not a shell process in remote host when using SSH with specific command?

Tags: linux, ssh

I call this in my local machine

```
ssh -t   anon@192.168.50.81 -p 10086 'echo $SHELL && pstree'
```

I got `/bin/zsh` and a normal pstree output without shell process.

Why? And is the first output a fake one?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, but `$SHELL` is expanding on the local end before `ssh` even runs.

Comment: The remote shell may be smart enough to `exec` the `pstree` command without forking.

Comment: Try changing it to `pstree && echo foo`. Some shells will run the last command with `exec` rather than forking.

Comment: Use single quotes around the command to echo the remote value of `$SHELL`.

Comment: @Barmar I use the single quotes and it print the "/bin/zsh", I am sure the sure is binded to my user anon in the remote. But why it started a shell when I using only ssh with commands to run even without the -t option(no terminal to bind). And why the zsh process was not in the output of pstree?

Comment: It has to start a shell so it can execute shell operations like `&&`. It doesn't matter whether you use `-t` or not.

Comment: I think `zsh` is one of the shells that optimizes the last command in a statement by using `exec` instead of forking a child. That's why you don't see it in `pstree`.

Comment: @Barmar yes are right when I chsh to bash in remote it appeared in the pstree output. But I still can't image its implement method when shell is zsh, I think whether the zsh fork the pstree process or not doesn't change the fact it will show in the pstree output as a real running process.Unless i only was alive at the beginning to interpret the $SHELL environment variable and the && and fork or exec the pstree and directly exit itself? I am not sure the mechanism whether the pstree process will be handled as a subprocess of systemed. But it is actually as a subprocess of sshd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some shells, like `zsh`, do not fork a child process to execute the last command in a command line or script. Since the exit status of the line or script is the same as the exit status of the last command, they call `exec()` in the shell process without forking. So if you execute

```
sleep 5 && pstree
```

it will fork a child for `sleep`, wait for it to finish, then call `exec()` to run `pstree`.

Since the `pstree` process replaces the shell, you don't see the shell in the process tree. `pstree` will be the child of `sshd`.

If you change it to

```
pstree && sleep 5
```

then you should see the shell in the `pstree` output, because `pstree` is no longer the last command.